# Replacing part of string python

Tags: python, string

I have two strings that look like this:

```
a="{'c1': null, 'c2': 'null', 'c3': 'abcd', 'c4': null}"
```

and I'd like to replace to convert null into Null and to add quotes if they don't exist, so the outcome would be like this:

```
"{'c1': 'Null', 'c2': 'Null', 'c3': 'abcd', 'c4': 'Null'}"
```

Can I get some help with this please ?

PS: I'm using python 2.7

Thank you in advance

**Edit:**

I tried this:

```
def replace(element):
  element.replace('null', "'Null'") #which doesn't work as I want beacause it adds quotes even if they already exist
```

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work ?

Comment: I added what I tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the simplest case, you might solve this with a regular expression:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r"('?null'?)", "'Null'", "{'abcd': null}")
"{'abcd': 'Null'}"
>>> re.sub(r"('?null'?)", "'Null'", "{'abcd': 'null'}")
"{'abcd': 'Null'}"
>>>
```

but from the look of you example and the comment (which should really be part of your question) mentionning you might have a lot more in the string, I suspect you are dealing with json here. If that's the case, the proper solution (the only robust solution actually) is to deserialize your string to Python (using `json.loads(...)`), update the resulting Python object (usually a dict, but might be a list of dicts or might contains lists containing dicts etc), then serialize it back with `json.dumps()`.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, many thanks :)

Comment: @kab please carefully read my caveat - the `re.sub()` solution is very brittle (try it on `"{'nullificator':'nullify'}"` for example).

Answer (score -1):

Basically you want the first part from the given string and the second part should be Null

```
def fun(strig):
  return str(strig.split(':')[0])+":'Null'}"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but what I mentionned above is just an example , I might have d={'abcd': null, ..........}

Comment: @kab if your string can contains more than what's in your question, do yourself and the world a favour: edit your post to make this point clear and post a couple (eventually shortened) examples of __real__ data.

Comment: "strig.split(':')[0])+":'Null'}" is already a string, why pass it to `str` ?